# Factory implementation with enum

Tags: java

I'm following the Java factory pattern to define different PDF templates for a report I'm creating.

```
Template
TemplateFactory
Example1Template
Example2Template
```

In the concrete classes Example1Template and Example2Template I need to have a collection of pages that are contained in the PDF template which is different for each implementation. Currently I have a HashMap of values:

```
    private static final Map<String,Integer> PAGES;
    static
    {
        PAGES = new HashMap<>();
        PAGES.put("COVER", 1);
        PAGES.put("DEFAULT", 2);
        PAGES.put("PAGE_TYPE_1", 3);
        PAGES.put("PAGE_TYPE_2", 4);
        PAGES.put("PAGE_TYPE_3", 5);
    }
```

Ideally I'd like to use something like an enum where I can benefit from type safety and limited inputs rather than just using a string key but I'm struggling to get it to work.

Edit:
What is the best way to achieve this in the context of Factory pattern?

`Template template = TemplateFactory.get(TemplateType.CORPORATE);`

Then I can change my code to use template.PAGES.COVER where I am currently using "COVER" with the HashMap specifying the page. This is the part I can't get to work with the Factory pattern.

Comment: `enum Page { COVER(1), DEFAULT(2), ... }`, define a field to hold the number, constructor to set the field and a getter.

Answer (score 0):

Java enums are in the end ... just special versions of classes. This means that you can make use of a custom constructor, like:

```
public enum Whatever {
   Bar(1), Foo(2);

   private final int whoCares;
   private Whatever(int value) { whoCares = value;  }

   public int getValue() { return whoCares; }
```

Of course, the interesting part might be ... that sooner or later that you would need multiple such enums - all carrying the same enum instance names, but providing access to different properties.

Answer (score 0):

Use valuable enum (the value is set in a private constructor so it cannot be changed):

```
public enum Pages {
    COVER(1), 
    DEFAULT(2);

    private final int value;
    Pages(int value) { this.value = value; }
    public int getValue() { return value; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a quick demonstration of implementation using Map vs. implementation using Enum:

```
public class TestEnum {

    public enum PAGES {

        COVER(1),
        DEFAULT(2),
        PAGE_TYPE_1(3),
        PAGE_TYPE_2(4),
        PAGE_TYPE_3(5);

        public final int value;
        PAGES(int value) {
            this.value = value;
        }
    }

    private static final Map<String,Integer> pages;
        static
        {
            pages = new HashMap<>();
            pages.put("COVER", 1);
            pages.put("DEFAULT", 2);
            pages.put("PAGE_TYPE_1", 3);
            pages.put("PAGE_TYPE_2", 4);
            pages.put("PAGE_TYPE_3", 5);
        }


        public static void main(String[] args) {

            for ( PAGES page : PAGES.values()) {

                System.out.println("Enum value is "+ page.value  + "    Map vlaue is "+ pages.get(page.name()));
            }
        }
}
```

The printout is :

Enum value is 1 Map vlaue is 1

Enum value is 2 Map vlaue is 2

Enum value is 3 Map vlaue is 3

Enum value is 4 Map vlaue is 4

Enum value is 5 Map vlaue is 5

Comment: Thanks it works in this context but in the context of the Factory pattern where i need to use it like Template template = TemplateFactory.get(TemplateType.CORPORATE);  and then template.PAGES.COVER is where I can't get it to work.